# Cannot use downloaded packages

Tags: python, package, installation

I downloaded pip and a series of other packages from my cmd but they don't import when I want to use them in Eclipse.

I've checked that they are there with pip list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Eclipse to look for the installed packages within the site-packages folder within your python installation.

Site-packages is the target directory of manually built Python packages. When you build and install Python packages from source (using distutils, probably by executing python setup.py install), you will find the installed modules in site-packages by default.

You can follow these steps to add it within Eclipse:

```
1. Find out the path to the folder ../site-packages/ of your corresponding python version. ( e.g /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-package for python3.6 on Ubuntu )
2. Open eclipse preferences and go to PyDev -> Interpreter - Python.
3. On the left side of the lower box, click on New Folder.
4. Add the navigate to ../site-packages/ of your corresponding python version.
5. Hit Open.
6. Hit Apply.
7. Hit Ok.
```